# Rails view Problems with ActiveRecord Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this Query:

```
<% @answer = Answer.where(:question_id => @question.id, :correct => 1) %>
```

Result is:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Answer id: 535, body: "d", notice: "", correct: true, question_id: 50, created_at: "2015-09-26 10:09:10", updated_at: "2015-09-26 10:09:10">]>
```

When I want to do this:

```
<%= @answer.body %>
```

I got this error:

```
undefined method `body' for <Answer::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000e99b7c8>
```

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `where` query returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` which is a collection of objects.

In order for that code to work, you have to append `.last` or `.first` or `.find(id)` to return a single object.

```
<% @answer = Answer.where(:question_id => @question.id, :correct => 1).last %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with .first.

Whats the difference in this case that .first dosn't work?

Comment: There should not be a difference, if you aren't getting a response from `@answer.body` it probably means `:body` attribute is empty. Try the `where` query in your `rails console` so that you can see the full response.

Answer (score 3):

> undefined method `body' for
>   Answer::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000e99b7c8

As you see `@answer` returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is a collection of records/objects, so you just can't simply use `@answer.body`.

***Solution:***

You can iterate over `@answer`

```
<% @answer.each do |answer| %>
  <%= answer.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want one record, you can use `find_by` instead of `where`.

Answer (score 0):

`where` returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)(looks like an array, but not), which is a collection of model objects, so @answer is a collection, you can't use it to invoke `body` attribute directly.

You can do like this:

```
<% @answer = Answer.where(:question_id => @question.id, :correct => 1).first %>
```

or:

```
<% @answer = Answer.find_by_question_id_and_correct(@question.id, 1) %>
```

It will return a single object if record exists.